# Force how iOS renders <select>

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, html-select, picker

iOS renders the `<select>` elements as a "wheel picker" (some places I read "wheel selector", "picker", etc.)

I'm working on a project exclusively for iPads and I found that they do not render the `<select>` the same way.

This may be due to the fact, that this is a **Cordova/Angular** app OR that the **screen size** is not small enough for it to "kick in".

Does anyone know a way through which I could "force" how the `<select>` is rendered?

Comment: iPad doesn't render the select the same way the iPhone does and you can't change that. If you want a "wheel picker" on iPad you could try to create/search a plugin that uses the native UIPickerView

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the tip. I also found UIPickerView, however, I thought I could only use that if I'm building a native app. How could I use a plugin from Angular?

Comment: You can use native classes on cordova plugins. I've find this one https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview, but probably there are some more.

Comment: So.. I've checked this and if I specify it in the question, that I want a solution that works without accessing XCode, I'm basically stuck with *there is no such solution*, right?

Comment: It seems that the plugin docs are not updated, try to install it using ```cordova plugin add https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-pickerview```, you won't need Xcode